# Ionic / Angular check value in template if it is set

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i have the following problem:

I hava an array of blog posts. Some of then have photos, others not. I want so show the first photo if there photos are set. Who can I check if the url value in my array is set?

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Blogposts</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <ion-card>
      <img [src]="post.photos[0].original_size.url"/>
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-title>
          {{post.summary}}
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a **`*ngIf`** with **`photos.length`** with **`safe navigation operator`** to check if the posts are defined since you are making asynchronous request to get the results.

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <ion-card *ngIf="post?.photos?.length > 0">
          <img [src]="post?.photos[0]?.original_size.url"/>
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
            </ion-card-title>
              {{post.summary}}
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-item>
```

Comment: sry. Doesn't work: "cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf` and assign the property using `let`. I would also combine existential operators to prevent any crashes:

```
<img *ngIf="post?.photos[0]?.original_size?.url; let url" [src]="url">
```